# How do I use the Channel Handlers in Sendbird

Tags: javascript, html, messaging, sendbird

I'm trying to use the SendBird API to create a simple chat for a demo but I can't seem to get the Channel Handler to work properly. I don't know where I'm supposed to put it but it seems anywhere I try doesn't work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you also have any suggestions for alternatives that I could get running in a day or two, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run SendBird sample UI projects?

SendBird provides sample projects for all platforms. You can find them in documentation menu.

https://docs.sendbird.com/